# how to calculate the fundamental group using van kampen theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

i'm really stuck in calculating the fundamental group (pi1 ) of this surface... can someone please help me?....
i'm trying to use the van Kampen theorem but i don't know how to take the open sets here to work

[image]

Comment: If I interprete your drawing well, this is homeomorphic to a torus, so no need to use Van Kampen

Comment: torus? i can't understand how?

Comment: the knotted tube in the middel is just homeomorphic to a straight tube

Comment: @ArtW : Thank you.

Comment: but it is clinging from both sides to the sphare... sorry i can't understand how  is it isomorphic to a straght line, if i dont consider the both sides it's tru but now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ArtW pointed out in the comments, the surface seems homeomorphic to a torus. This can be argued as follows:

- The knotted tunnel in the middle of the sphere never self-intersects or interacts with the sphere, so it is homeomorphic to a straight tunnel passing through the sphere
- A tunnel passing through a sphere is homeomorphic to a tunnel similarly connecting pole to pole but going outside the sphere instead of inside
- Now imagine deflating the sphere so it's the same width as the tunnel, giving a torus